# Does the Nasadiya Sukta mention light?

Tags: rig-veda

Is there a translation of Nasadiya Sukta from Rigveda that incorporates the idea of light (darkness)?  If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Have you read Nasadiya Sukta?

Answer (score 1):

The English translated version of The Nasadiya Sukta-
"
Nasadiya Sukta (Hymn of non-Eternity, origin of universe):

There was neither non-existence nor existence then;
Neither the realm of space, nor the sky which is beyond;
What stirred? Where? In whose protection?

There was neither death nor immortality then;
No distinguishing sign of night nor of day;
That One breathed, windless, by its own impulse;
Other than that there was nothing beyond.

Darkness there was at first, by darkness hidden;
Without distinctive marks, this all was water;
That which, becoming, by the void was covered;
That One by force of heat came into being;

Who really knows? Who will here proclaim it?
Whence was it produced? Whence is this creation?
Gods came afterwards, with the creation of this universe.
Who then knows whence it has arisen?

Whether God's will created it, or whether He was mute;
Perhaps it formed itself, or perhaps it did not;
The Supreme Brahman of the world, all pervasive and all knowing
He indeed knows, if not, no one knows
—Rigveda 10.129

Darkness there was at first, by darkness hidden. So later it was different. The negation could be later darkness was there at first, but not hidden by further darkness. Or another possibility is that later there was light. The word devas itself means shining ones. So their appearance would bring light. Surya the lighted face of Savitr would appear and cast his life-generating rays ☀️.
So light is not mentioned per se, but it definitely appears with the Gods, the devas, the shining ones.

The Sanskrit is beautiful -
[image: Rig Veda 10.129 Nasadiya Suktam]

Comment: Awesome answer! watch this: https://www.sahajmarg.org/babuji-maharaj

Comment: you need to give credit to the translator when doing a reference. Who is the translator?

Comment: Swamiji Pranaam, the translation is from —Rigveda 10.129 (Abridged, Tr: Kramer / Christian)